# CocoaPods test target Library not loaded exit code 82

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

This appears to be an issue with CocoaPods, asking here first as per the [guidelines](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Using Xcode 7.3.1, CocoaPods 1.0.1, 1.0.0-beta6 and 1.1.0-beta1

Create a new pod project using `pod lib create SwiftTest`

- Language? Swift
- Demo? Yes
- Test frameworks? None
- View based testing? No

Add a single class function to the auto-generated `ReplaceMe.swift` file to test the projects integration.

Calling the function from the example project works as expected.

Calling the function from the test project fails with the following error:

```
The bundle “SwiftTest_Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
(dlopen_preflight(/...): Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftTest.framework/SwiftTest ... Reason: image not found)
Program ended with exit code: 82
```

Example project: https://github.com/NextFaze/SwiftTest

Comment: See CocoaPods issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5750

Comment: I just tried a different simulator and it worked

Answer (score 7):

Issue can be fixed by changing the `Podfile` to:

```
use_frameworks!

def standard_pods
    pod 'SwiftTest', :path => '../'
end

target 'SwiftTest_Example' do
  standard_pods
end

target 'SwiftTest_Tests' do
  standard_pods
end
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. The source provided the story https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5750 and after digging around it looks like a bug from 1.0.0 that they are aware and should fix but they don't..

Answer (score 0):

I was developing a CocoaPod and had to change its name in Xcode 8 (rumours say, that there is going to be a better renaming refactor functionality in Xcode 9).
(This caused so many troubles BTW!!)

After I fixed all the renaming issues, I wanted my tests to run as well, but that error occurred. All I had to do is to set up the Host Application:

In Targets > Select the test target > General > you will find the Host Application under Testing. Mine was empty/grayed-out due to this renaming issue. I selected my host application and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the test target didn't include `.framework`

It started to work, after following this step:

- Select test target > Build Phases > Add the missing framework to both `Link Binary With Libraries` and `Copy Frameworks`